# Show name contact instead address in email intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I was trying an iOS app, and when I choose to send an email, the address was hidden, and instead it displayed a word (a name).

I'm trying to do the same in android, with no results until now.

Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"Name Here <test@email.com>"});
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
startActivity(intent);
```

Note the format of the email address: `Name Here <test@email.com>`

Hope this helps!